# How to make Nginx virtual host work? (page not found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, web-server, virtualbox

Running Ubuntu 13.10 in VirtualBox.

I've put my website in this folder:

[image]

And created the log folder on /srv/www/streamsy.com/logs/.

I've done these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/streamsy.com/public_html
sudo chmod 755 /srv/www
```

The config files looks like this:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/streamsy.com:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name streamsy.com;

  access_log /srv/www/streamsy.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log /srv/www/streamsy.com/logs/error.log;

  location / {
      root /srv/www/streamsy.com/public_html/;
      index index.html;
  }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";


  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/streamsy.com;
}
```

I've enabled the streamsy.com file with:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/streamsy.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/streamsy.com
```

Editted /etc/hosts, but with real ip instead of x:

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       lalle-VM
 217.72.x.x streamsy.com
```

Restarting:

```
sudo service nginx restart

* Restarting nginx nginx                                                [ OK ]
```

Result, localhost work too:

[image]

No errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I want to be able to access my nginx server remotely on my public IP. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by opening port 80 in router.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your /etc/hosts file as follows.

`127.0.0.1       localhost streamsy.com`

but this way you won't get reach real streamsy.com 
because it's hosted on 96.126.97.60 (unless this is your ip address)

Comment: Nope that's not my ip, streamsy.com is just a label I have, I could have used example.com or so instead. How can I access my site remotely? I wish to type my real ip (217.72.x.x) into the address bar and load the website. My router have forwarded ports 80

Comment: Your remote computer has to solve your domain/label as your server's public IP address. and of course you have to use NAT if your server is behind any router.